# PDF displayed incorrectly in iOS 4.3 but works in iOS 5.0 and above

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, pdf, uiwebview

I have the following code that displays a pdf just using a simple UIWebView in InfoViewController:

```
- (void)loadPDF
{
    NSString *pathToInfoPDF = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"info" 
        ofType:@"pdf"];
    NSURL *pdfUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToInfoPDF];
    NSURLRequest *pdfUrlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:pdfUrl];
    [self.pdfWebView loadRequest:pdfUrlRequest]; 
}
```

This is presented to the user using the an info button as a modal view:

```
- (IBAction)showInfo:(id)sender 
{
    NSLog(@"Info Button pressed!");
    InfoViewController *infoViewController = [[InfoViewController alloc] 
        initWithNibName:@"InfoViewController" bundle:nil];
    infoViewController.delegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController: infoViewController animated: YES];
}
```

This works great in iOS 5.0 and above:

[image: pdf view in iOS 5.0]

However, when I attempt to load this in iOS 4.3.2, the page isn't displayed at fullscreen:

[image: pdf view in iOS 4.3.2]

Is there anyway to make the pdf fullscreen with devices using iOS 4.3 as well as iOS 5.0 and above?  Or is there a problem with the way I'm displaying a pdf in a UIWebView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `scalesPageToFit = YES;`. It should work.

Comment: Awesome it worked!  It looks like I was focusing more on the pdf itself, rather than trying some of the UIWebView properties.  I actually just checked the "Scales Page To Fit" checkbox in Interface Builder for the UIWebView itself.